# Any word (adjective preferably) that used to describe an achievement of pulling off something big out of the blue and not due to his abilities

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, someone managed to make a basketball half court shot but it was him trying a thousand times not because he is that good. "Lucky" could be used as the word but I wonder if theres any word that emphasises on the great quality of the achievement, with negative connotation or an undertone of it being something that only happens once in a lifetime and shows the person doing it is not really that impressive.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is a duplicate of [Word for an event that will likely never happen again](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/508125/291924), however, I'm holding off on casting a binding vote on that because there needs to be clarification about the "negative" and "not that impressive" aspect of what's being sought. (The current answer doesn't have that sense to it, nor do the answers in the question I think is *likely* a duplicate.) Please provide additional context for this negatively—such as a possible scenario where it would be used in that specific way.

Comment: [Similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/534493/365490) --- [Another similar one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/442678/is-there-a-word-for-something-happening-after-you-wish-for-it/442737#442737) (3 similar questions)

Answer (score 3):

A  ***[fluke:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/fluke)***

> something good that has happened that is the result of chance instead of skill or planning:
>
> - The first goal was just a fluke.

(Cambridge Dictionary)